# Who gave Rabbi Soloveitchik (the Rav) Semichah?

Tags: rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

I heard it was from Rabbi Chaim Ozer, but I've also heard that it was from another rabbi?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that he had other semicha as well but the Dvar Avrohom,    Rav Avraham Dov Ber Kahana Shapiro (Rav of Kovno) is said to have given him semicha.

Comment: Indeed. On page 6 of "The Life and Impact of Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik z”l" it writes: He became so proficient that the Rav of Kovno, Rav Avraham Dov Ber Kahana Shapiro gave him semicha  - https://images.shulcloud.com/590/uploads/Media/Rabbis-on-Rotation/TheLifeandImpactofRabbiJosephB.SoloveitchikPart1.pdf

Comment: I'm told that said semicha included the phrase *v'halacha k'moso bechol makom*!